# PHP: libssh2 prefix on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, php, pecl

So I decided to install the libssh2 library using PECL.

I'm at the point where it is asking me to specify a libssh2 prefix:

```
5 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
libssh2 prefix? [/usr] :
```

What am I supposed to put here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have the libssh2 development package installed, via:

```
sudo aptitude install libssh2-1-dev
```

The PECL installer should then find the necessary files fine.

Alternatively, you could install `libssh2-php`, the PHP bindings for libssh2. Installing this package will install all the necessary dependencies (including `libssh2-1`):

```
sudo aptitude install libssh2-php
```

Comment: Tried libssh2-php and I think it worked! Thanks!

Comment: For Centos users the commands are 
`yum install libssh2-devel` then `pecl install ssh2-0.12`