# PHP ssh extension

Tags: installation, ssh, php

I'm trying to install the ssh extension of PHP [following this article](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/).

My machine is a `Linux mpriki 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Mon Jun 21 05:58:44 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux (lenny13 distrubition`

When I type `aptitude install libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php` everything seems to be OK, but when I run `php -m |grep ssh2`, the shell doesn't return anything, so I tried to follow the alternative installation.

First of all, I tried to download it with `wget` from here: http://surfnet.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/libssh2/libssh2-0.14.tar.gz, but there was no file to download, so I tried another link: http://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-0.14.tar.gz

Then, when I type `pecl install -f ssh2` is see the following message:

```
root@mpriki:~# pecl install -f ssh2
WARNING: failed to download pecl.php.net/ssh2 within preferred state "stable", will instead download version 0.11.3, stability "beta"
downloading ssh2-0.11.3.tgz ...
Starting to download ssh2-0.11.3.tgz (23,062 bytes)
........done: 23,062 bytes
5 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
 1. libssh2 prefix? : autodetect

1-1, 'all', 'abort', or Enter to continue:
```

I find [this on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/82489/php-libssh2-prefix-on-ubuntu-9-10) but when I run `aptitude install libssh2-1-dev`, it seems the package has been already been installed.

**Edit:** I found [this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) but even though I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
1-1, 'all', 'abort', or Enter to continue:
```

Enter a number (between 1 and 1) to install that module from the list; or the word "`all`" to install all found modules; or "`abort`" to abort installation.

Comment: yes but then (type 1) i see this `libssh2 prefix? [autodetect]`

Comment: ...Enter a prefix where you want libssh2 to be installed to, or press Enter to have the best prefix auto-detected.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), if possible.  It's easier to install, easier to use, more feature packed and faster even then libssh2.

Comment: i now this library, anyway i found the solution in my problem..
The problem was in ssh2.c file
A patch file must be included